# PHP MVC Best Practice with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, doctrine

I would like to develop in PHP using Doctrine as the ORM, assuming that Doctrine act as the Model. I know that there's a web framework such as Symfony which uses Doctrine as default, but I need to know if there's a good solution to deploy PHP + Doctrine in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) is a great PHP framework and there are many good resources for integrating Doctrine and ZF.

In particular, for Doctrine 1, check out the Zendcast:

http://www.zendcasts.com/introducing-doctrine-1-2-integration/2009/11/

For Doctrine 2, check out the the application resource and bootstrap code in:

https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2

or

https://github.com/marsbomber/zf1-doctrine2

Comment: IMHO, ZF is a 'heavy' framework, I'll consider a lightweight framework.

Comment: With the appropriate cache, ZF is one of the fastest frameworks. But if you need Speed, you need to try Yii

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find appropriate place in your MVC solution to put Doctrine initialization code. Example from our framework: https://github.com/ysubach/mvcskel/blob/master/lib/MvcSkel/Filter/DoctrineInit.php

Once it's done you can easily call model methods from controller classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the github skeleton project I used, it did the doctrine 2 initialisation with Zend Franework 1.11.2 in the bootstrap, nice and clean, using model for entities & model repository for business logic. Unit tests & ant build script too for you TDD developers out there.

https://github.com/eddiejaoude/Zend-Framework--Doctrine-ORM--PHPUnit--Ant--Jenkins-CI--TDD-

ZF is an awesome php framework & combining it with doctrine makes it a very powerful combination.

Enjoy